# how to Sort Grade in Array

Tags: c++

I want to sort their grades in descending order. I just don't know how using bubble sort..

```
void computegrade(string name[], int studentno[], float ave[], int top)
{
if (top==0){
    cout<<"Nothing to display\n";
}
 cout<<"Students are: " <<"\n" <<"\n";
 for (int x=top-1; x>=0; x--)
 {
    cout<<"Student Name: " <<name[x] <<endl;
    cout<<"Student No: " <<studentno[x] <<endl;
    cout<<"Average: " <<ave[x];
}
 }
```

Comment: You should post your bubble sort implementation so we can assist with fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend first creating a struct or a class that would contain the student information rather than passing all the arrays individually.
Once you've done that you can pass the struct/class array containing your students to your function and then sort the array using bubble-sort by comparing the grades and then swapping the entire struct/class.

```
student students[number_of_students];
//load the student data here
computegrate(students,top);
```

then inside the function compare and swap if necessary

```
if(students[i-1].ave < students[i].ave){
student temp = students[i-1];
students[i-1] = students[i];
students[i] = temp;
}
```

You should be familiar with the full implementation of bubble-sort, if not then check your textbook or notes or some online tutorials.
You will have to rewrite your function to take an array of students.
The upside is you don't have to deal with all the individual data but rather the structure as a whole as demonstrated here with swapping the 2 student objects.

Without classes or structs you would have to individually swap the student information in all of the arrays you have.

Comment: Using a structure is excellent advice, but using bubble sort should be prefaced with a "If you can't use `std::sort`,"

Comment: What's wrong with `std::swap()` ?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, they can use std::swap()
And definitely they should use something else, I just assumed that they might be doing this for school or uni work and using bubble is a requirement.